# Active Directory Group Synchronize in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have some AD groups, which is having some custom properties. Now I can access that AD group in SharePoint 2013 sites. Now my question is I want access(fetch the value) of those custom properties of the AD group and show it in the SharePoint WebPart page. Is this scenario achievable using user profile service? or using JSOM or CSOM ? I know I can access the value using Server side code by accessing the LDAP directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can define those custom properties in User Profile and map it to AD property.

Then you should do a full sync.

Now you can try accessing the profile properties via REST. I am not sure if custom properties get listed.

Comment: Ok. One thing I need to know, Can I see those group in User Profile service of Central Admin?

Comment: Yes those will groups are imported into SP as users

Comment: But when I am  searching by their name..I am not able to see that..Am I ding anything wrong?